# Does the location of custom onLoad code matter in Dynamics CRM 4?

Tags: javascript, crm

Good afternoon, all.  I have a question regarding form scripting.  Whenever I add code to a form event, for example onLoad, does the code's location in any existing code matter?  For example, I want to enable/disable a field based on the FormType value.  Does it matter if I place this code at the top or bottom of the current onLoad code?

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't matter the Javascript just searches for the right function in the entire document.